# Failed to load external module @babel/register

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I introduced babel/register.

**Question**

Why do I get this error message?

```
[20:08:38] Failed to load external module @babel/register
[20:08:38] Requiring external module babel-register
[20:08:43] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\es6\gulpfile.babel.js
[20:08:43] Starting 'build'...
[20:08:43] Starting 'clean'...
[20:08:43] Finished 'clean' after 33 ms
[20:08:43] Starting 'css'...
[20:08:43] Finished 'css' after 38 ms
[20:08:43] Starting 'pages'...
[20:08:43] Finished 'pages' after 136 ms
[20:08:43] Starting 'scripts'...
[20:08:44] Version: webpack 3.10.0
   Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    index.js  2.63 kB       0  [emitted]  index

  ERROR in multi ./app/js/index.js
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel' in 
  'C:\Users\wy\Desktop\es6'
  BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when 
  using loaders.
             You need to specify 'babel-loader' instead of 'babel',
             see https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-
  module-name-ex        tension-removed
 @ multi ./app/js/index.js
[20:08:45] Finished 'scripts' after 1.37 s
[20:08:45] Starting 'browser'...
[20:08:45] Starting 'server'...
[20:08:45] Finished 'server' after 80 渭s
```

Comment: Did you follow the information given to you in the error message? "BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders. **You need to specify 'babel-loader' instead of 'babel'**,"

Comment: Thanks, "BREAKING CHANGE" This error I have solved. However,“ Failed to load external module @babel/register ” the problem is still not solved...so sad..